# Passing value from Main Activity to Broadcast Receiver class on button click

Tags: android

I want to pass value from MainActivity class to BroadCast Receiver Class. This coding is done in MainActivity.Do i have to mention this action("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE") in manifest file also??

```
    public void broadcastIntent(View v){
                if(togglebutton.isChecked()){
                Intent i=new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
                String x="heyo";
                i.putExtra("xx", x);
                sendBroadcast(i);
                }else{
                }



Class x extending BroadcastReceiver....    

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent in) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                in.getExtras();
                String action=in.getAction();
                if(action.equals("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE")){
                    String u=in.getExtras().get("xx").toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"hi " +u, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"Intent detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
```

Comment: What happen, does you receiver get anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preferences. There is some [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) about that.

```
public void broadcastIntent(View v){
    Activity activity = (Activity) view.getContext()
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("xx",x);
    editor.commit();
    Intent i=new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

and then your code of broadcastReceiver.

```
Class x extending BroadcastReceiver....    

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent in) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String xx = sharedPref.getString("xx", "");
 }
```

Comment: It is showing error in this line i.e The method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity  &  context cannot be resolved to a variable

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Where are you using that broadcastIntent method?

Comment: It is showing error in this line also i.e The method context is undefined for the type Receiver

SharedPreferences sharedPref = context().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: I made changes in my answer please try now, after applying my changes.

Comment: I am using this code in main activity

public void broadcastIntent(View v){
  if(tb.isChecked()){
   String x="heyo";
   
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
       editor.putString("xx",x);
       editor.commit();
       Intent i=new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
       sendBroadcast(i);
  }else{
  }
 }

Comment: using this code in receiver class

if(action.equals("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE")){
 
   
   SharedPreferences sharedPref = context().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String xx = sharedPref.getString("xx", "");

Comment: I have updated that code too. Please update it in your project.

Comment: thanks..
but it is showing error the method context is undefined in Receiver.........

SharedPreferences sharedPref = context().getPreferences(
     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: oh... try to review it use `context.getPreferences`... not `context().getPreferences`

Comment: than its saying method getPrefrences(int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: I am not able to do through this.......I had given a togglebutton in mainactivity and i want when the togglebutton is checked and if the phone goes in airplone mode than it displays a toast...... and if togglebutton is unchecked than nothing happens.

Comment: Ask another question maybe stack can help you.

Comment: I have asked another also but i am not getting answer for that also......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243404/how-to-pass-value-from-activity-to-broadcast-receiver-class-on-togglebutton-clic

Comment: hey i have one more query could you please help

Comment: I will look on it in free time.

Comment: do i post here or email you??

Comment: Please ask ont the stack and share it to me here.

Answer (score 0):

Register your BroadcastReceiver in your menifest and here you go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml.
See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) for the documentation of the  element.

Example:

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.intent.action.MY_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note: I don't know what you are trying to achieve in the end but the android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE action is probably not the right action that you want to send out yourself.

Comment: i defined that bt i am not able to pass data

Comment: If you actually tried to send the AIRPLANE_MODE action as a broadcast then that will probably fail with: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE. <- this action can only be sent by apps that have the required permission to send this broadcast (as it's used by the system). Again, I don't know what you want to do in the end but this action is probably not the right one that you want to send. If you want to send your own receiver some data then you can define your own Intent action and use this instead

Comment: I had given a togglebutton in mainactivity and i want when the togglebutton is checked and if the phone goes in airplone mode than it displays a toast...... and if togglebutton is unchecked than nothing happens.